Add MorphTargets in the gltf file
I am searching for realistic Avatar 3D models for lipsync I found the models but in that model, there are no MorphTargets so I'm not able to do lipsync with that avatar. Manually I want to add it Can it possible ??
I want to solve how I can manually add a new mesh of all the parts of the face like eyes lips teeth, I can add manually in that gltf file and MorphTargets.
@readyplayerme is giving us Every mesh and also giving us MorphTargets.

Morph targets can be created by a model artist as "Shape Keys" in Blender (you tagged this Q with Blender). It takes work and some artistic talent.  Blender's Shape Keys export to glTF as Morph Targets.
